# Game Intent Action for Android

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play-games

Question:

I've been tasked with getting a list of current games on an Android Device (pretty simple in theory), I was wondering, if there is a fancy way to do this without using custom urls?

I know that we can view all apps on the installed on an android device, I was wondering if there was a Game Filter of some kind?

Thanks!
Best Regards,
Christopher Steven

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, the only required meta data to prove an app is a game looks like this in the manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

If you can figure out how to check for that then you can do it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to branch from this and post what I find =]